# google map click marker function issue

Tags: jquery, google-maps

Can you only have one window.location.href?

The issue is only the last click function for a marker is correct when clicked. the rest are even tho the output is different (which is correct) they always open up the last url.

Note the cfloop.

```
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), options);
   // Create an Array for the Markers
   var markers = [];
     <cfloop array="#rc.details.poi.getPageRecords()#" index="local.poi">
      var latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(#local.poi.getpoiLat()#,#local.poi.getpoiLong()#);
      //var iconImg = '/assets/images/pin-50.png';

     <cfif !ArrayIsEmpty(local.poi.getimages())>
         var iconImg = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://#CGI.HTTP_HOST#/plugins/api/index.cfm/image/#local.poi.getimages()[1].getimageID()#/50/50/get?apiKey=#application.factory.getBean('authenticationService').getAPIKey('image', 'GET')#&defaulttype=poi", null, new google.maps.Point(0,0), new google.maps.Point(0,0));
        <cfelse>
         var iconImg = new google.maps.MarkerImage("http://#CGI.HTTP_HOST#/plugins/api/index.cfm/image/1be71dec-a525-404f-a148-48ad74e46397/50/50/get?apiKey=#application.factory.getBean('authenticationService').getAPIKey('image', 'GET')#&defaulttype=poi", null, new google.maps.Point(0,0), new google.maps.Point(0,0));
      </cfif>

   var shadow = new google.maps.MarkerImage('/plugins/assets/images/AirTag50.png',
        // The shadow image is larger in the horizontal dimension
        // while the position and offset are the same as for the main image.
        new google.maps.Size(50, 80),
        new google.maps.Point(0,0),
        new google.maps.Point(0, 7));
        // Shapes define the clickable region of the icon.
        // The type defines an HTML <area> element 'poly' which
        // traces out a polygon as a series of X,Y points. The final
        // coordinate closes the poly by connecting to the first
        // coordinate.
    var shape = {
        coord: [1, 10, 10, 50, 55, 50,55 , 1],
        type: 'poly'
    };

    var URLonClick = "#buildURL(action='public:scape.view',queryString='scapeID=#local.poi.getScape().getscapeID()#&airtag=#local.poi.getpoiID()#')#";
     var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: latLng, map: map, draggable: false, title: 'Click to View AirTag', icon: iconImg, shadow: shadow, shape: shape, url: URLonClick });
     // Action Listener for the Marker
     google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(event) {
            window.location.href = marker.url;
        });


      markers.push(marker);
    </cfloop>

    var mcOptions = {gridSize: 50, maxZoom: 15};
    var markerCluster = new MarkerClusterer(map, markers, mcOptions);
```

Answer (score 1):

It's about function closure. As you create markers inside the loop, the value of var URLonClick keeps getting updated, so in the end it has the last value that you put on it.
The solution is to create your markers in a separate function to which you pass the necessary parameters.

Good reading on the subject, here:

http://econym.org.uk/gmap/closure.htm

Answer (score 0):

The problem is **`marker.url`**

You are overwriting the marker-variable on every loop, so `marker.url` will always point to the url-member of the last marker that has been created.

Use **`this.url`** instead of **`marker.url`** to access the url-member of the clicked marker.